# How do I take multi-line input from Codeforces?

Tags: python

Codefores requires a lot of multi-line input. For example:

https://codeforces.com/contest/71/problem/A

TLDR: read this and reduce length of all words
:

```
4
word
localization
internationalization
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

I used this solution, which I believe is correct and works for me:

```
lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break
input = '\n'.join(lines)


tab=input.splitlines()

numb=tab[0]

tab.pop(0)

for i in tab:
    wordTab=[]
    if len(i)>10:
        wordTab.append(i[:1])
        wordTab.append(i[-1:])
        print(f"{i[:1]}{len(i)-2}{i[-1:]}")
    else:
        print(i)
```

Yet i got an error (on their side). How can I make Codeforces accept multi-line input in Python?

Comment: `input()` doesn't return false if user doesn't take action for a while. In your case, your program just hang at `line = input()` after the server finishs sending out its data. After a certain time with no value returned, your program is killed by the server and the error is sent to you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup where I have two files called "input.txt" and "output.txt". That is where I write the code locally and then I have a FILE params which I make it True and False when I have to submit to Codeforces. Here is an example of the same problem you had mentioned. It worked fine with 77 ms as running time.

```
import sys
from os import path

FILE = False # if needed change it while submitting

if FILE:
    sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r')
    sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w')

def get_int():
    return int(sys.stdin.readline())

def get_string():
    return sys.stdin.readline().strip()

n = get_int()

final_result = []
for i in range(n):
    word = get_string()
    if len(word) > 10:
        word = word[0] + str(len(word) - 2) + word[-1]
    final_result.append(word)

for item in final_result:
    sys.stdout.write(item)
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Comment: This is the best way. Also check out this template: https://codeforces.com/contest/1424/submission/94829431

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

```
n = int(input())
arr = []
 
for i in range(n) :
    word = input()
    if len(word) > 10 :
        arr.append(word[0] + str(len(word) - 2) + word[len(word)-1])
    else :
        arr.append(word)
 
print("\n".join(arr))
```

Answer (score -2):

```py
lines = '''4
word
localization
internationalization
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis'''

input = '\n'.join(lines)


tab=lines.splitlines()

for i in tab:
    wordTab=[]
    if len(i)>10:
        start= i[:1]
        middle = len(i)-2
        end= i[-1:]
        print(f"{start}{len(i)-2}{end}")
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. This works on my end, but not for Codeforces.

Comment: It could be that Codeforces uses python 2 and not 3 so... the input function should be written differently. Instead of writing it with print() try raw_input() and see if it works for you.